# In git, how can I pull changes from another branch into the working tree?

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

I did some interesting work in a topic branch. Now I want to clean those changes before committing into the main branch. So I'd like to pull all those changes into the working tree: have the working tree contain the topic's branch version, with `git diff` showing all the changes from the master branch.

Is that possible? How do I do that?

EDIT: `git merge --no-ff topic && git reset --mixed HEAD^` seems to do the trick. If someone has a more elegant answer, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 5):

Don't know, if I understand you right

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff --no-commit topic
```

Comment: damn, I was like 30 seconds too late!

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work, it does exactly the same as `git merge` with no options.

Comment: No, it doesn't: On the one side it will not fast-forward (when possible) and on the other it will not commit the merge (will keep the changes in the working tree). You can also give `git merge --squash --no-commit` a try. However, as mentioned I suggest I get you wrong (I don't really get, what you want to achieve)

Comment: Yes, it does, I have tested it. I read the man page and I know it shouldn't, but it's just what it does. Anyways, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `git merge --no-commit --no-ff`

From the man page:

> With --no-commit perform the merge but pretend the merge failed and do
>   not autocommit, to give the user a chance to inspect and further tweak
>   the merge result before committing.

EDIT: we also need to specify --no-ff because a merge commit is not created in the case of a fast forward merge, so git does not understand what --no-commit means.

Comment: Same comment, unfortunately it doesn't work, probably because the merge is too simple (it's a fast-forward). --no-ff doesn't help either :-(

Comment: You're right, simply specifying --no-commit does not work in the case of a fast forward merge (because, well, this _is_ no merge commit in that case), but I just tried git merge --no-commit --no-ff topic and it does what you want it to do.

Comment: Actually, even with --no-commit, it creates a commit. I think the two options are somehow incompatible. Fortunately, doing git reset --mixed HEAD^ does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first rebase your topic branch, using `git rebase master`, then switch to the master branch using `git checkout master`, and last merge with `git merge --no-ff topic` or fast forward `git merge --ff-only topic` (where topic is the name of your topic branch).